# I loose search data when I click on pagination links

Tags: php, search, pagination

I am trying to applying pagination to my search results but everything is working even when I change the page numbers manually in url bar pagination work absolutely fine but when I use pagination links I lose all the search data. My code is as under kindly suggest me the solution. Thank you.

```
function search(){
        global $conn;
        $per_page = 3;
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;


        if(isset($_GET['search'])){

          $property_type = $_GET['property_type'];
          $society       = $_GET['society'];
          $min_area      = !empty($_GET['min_area'])?  $min_area = $_GET['min_area'] : 'NULL';
          $max_area      = !empty($_GET['max_area'])?  $max_area = $_GET['max_area'] : 'NULL';
          $min_price     = !empty($_GET['min_price'])? $min_price = $_GET['min_price'] : 'NULL';      
          $max_price     = !empty($_GET['max_price'])? $max_price = $_GET['max_price'] : 'NULL';
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM properties
              WHERE property_cat LIKE '%$property_type%'
                OR property_location LIKE '%$society%'
                OR property_area BETWEEN $min_area AND $max_area
                OR property_price BETWEEN $min_price AND $max_price
                ORDER BY property_id DESC
                LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";
                //echo $sql; die;
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          if($count == 0){
            redirect('index.php');
          }
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo "<li class='col-md-4 col-sm-6 type-rent maximum-height'>";
              echo "<div class='property-block'>";
                  echo "<a href='property-detail.html' class='property-featured-image'>";
                    echo "<img src='../admin/property_images/".$row['property_image'].".png' alt='feature image'>";
                    echo "<span class='images-count'><i class='fa fa-picture-o'></i> 2</span>";
                    echo "<span class='badges'>";
                      echo $row['is_parking'] == 0?'Rent':'Buy';
                    echo "</span>";
                echo "</a>";
                echo "<div class='property-info'>";
                    echo "<h4><a href='property-detail.html'>".$row['property_title']."</a></h4>";
                    echo "<span class='location'>".$row['property_location']."</span>";
                    echo "<div class='price'><strong>PKR</strong><span>".number_format($row['property_price'])."/-</span></div>";
                echo "</div>";
                echo "<div class='property-amenities clearfix'>";
                    echo "<span class='area'><strong>".$row['property_area']."</strong>";
                        echo $row['property_area_type']==1?'Marla':'Kanal';
                    echo "</span>";
                    echo "<span class='baths'><strong>".$row['property_baths']."</strong>Baths</span>";
                    echo "<span class='beds'><strong>".$row['property_beds']."</strong>Beds</span>";
                    echo "<span class='parking'><strong>";
                      echo $row['is_parking'] == 0?'No':'Yes';
                    echo "</strong>Parking</span>";
                    echo "</div>";
                echo "</div>";
              echo "</li>";
          }

          //Now select all from table for Pagination
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM properties
              WHERE property_cat LIKE '%$property_type%'
                OR property_location LIKE '%$society%'
                OR property_area BETWEEN $min_area AND $max_area
                OR property_price BETWEEN $min_price AND $max_price";

          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
          //Count the total records
          $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
          //echo $total_records;die;
          //Using Ceil Function to round off 
          $total_pages = ceil($total_records/$per_page);


          echo "<div class='text-center'>";
          echo "<ul class='pagination'>";
          // Going to First Page
          echo "<li><a href='search-page.php?page=1&property_type=".$property_type."&society=".$society."&min_area=".$min_area."&max_area=".$max_area."&min_price=".$min_price."&max_price=".$max_price."'>First</a></li>";
          // Pagination
          for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){
            echo "<li><a href='search-page.php?page=".$i."&property_type=".$property_type."&society=".$society."&min_area=".$min_area."&max_area=".$max_area."&min_price=".$min_price."&max_price=".$max_price."'>".$i."</a></li>";
          }
          // Going to Last Page
          echo "<li><a href='search-page.php?page=$total_pages&property_type=".$property_type."&society=".$society."&min_area=".$min_area."&max_area=".$max_area."&min_price=".$min_price."&max_price=".$max_price."'>Last</a></li>";
          echo "</ul>";
          echo "</div>";

        }
    }
```

Comment: i think your search variable is not in the url? 
$_GET['search']
<a href='search-page.php?page=".$i."&property_type=".$property_type."&society=".$society."&min_area=".$min_area."&max_area=".$max_area."&min_price=".$min_price."&max_price=".$max_price."'>".$i."</a>

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you are trying to say as I think all the search variables are in pagination urls